# How to show flutter bottom sheets, dialogue boxes over native bottom navigation bar?

Tags: flutter

I'm integrating a screen done in flutter to an existing native app. The native app has a bottom navigation bar that is present on all screens. The flutter screen needs to show bottom sheets and dialogue boxes, but all of these only show behind the bottom navigation bar (top navigation bar as well). Ideally, it should appear on top of all UI elements. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

mark useRootNavigator as **true** in *showModalBottomSheet* method

code shows like below:

```
showModalBottomSheet(
     shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
       borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
         topLeft: Radius.circular(25.0),
         topRight: Radius.circular(25.0),
       ),
     ),
     backgroundColor: Colors.white,
     context: context,
     isScrollControlled: true,
     useRootNavigator: true, /// add this line to show bottomsheet over navbar    
     builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return YourBottomLayout();
     },
    );
```

Comment: The showDialog method already has `useRootNavigator = true`. But it is still behind the bottom bar.